# JavaScript to export HTML tables to Excel checkbox issue

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel

i want to export html table to excel. All datas i can export. But I have issue with checkboxes. I cant shown my checkboxes in excel. there are some checked checkboxes too. Is that possible to show checkboxes in excel?

my codes ;

```
    function CreateExcelSheet(div,table){
  if (is_gecko) {
       var div =document.getElementById(div).innerHTML;
       windowUrl = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel,";
       var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl + encodeURIComponent(div), table);
  } 
  else if (is_ie5up){
        var x = document.getElementById(table).rows;
        var xls = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        xls.visible = true
        xls.Workbooks.Add
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        var y = x[i].cells;
        for (j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
            xls.cells(i + 1, j + 1).value = y[j].innerText;
        }
        }
  }
  else{
   alert("No support Excel please open whit Firefox!");
  } 
}
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this? It converts data to base64 that can be processed by Excel.

https://github.com/stephen-hardy/xlsx.js

Comment: i did, it didnt shown checkboxes. thanks by the way, its will be help for other project